# Get value from closed Excel workbook via HTTP link

Tags: excel, vba, excel-4.0

I have a bunch of Excel workbooks that are stored on a shared online directory (kind of like Dropbox) in different folders. I am creating a master workbook to pull values from these Excel workbooks into a summary. While testing I've managed to create one that works if the workbooks are stored in my disk drives and I refer to their directories, but not via the HTTP links they are stored on.

I'm currently using the `ExecuteExcel4Macro` macro to retrieve values from closed workbooks on my computer and passing the directory as the argument. Some code for example which works if it's a directory on the hard drive:

```
Private Function GetValue(path, file, sheet, ref)
'   Retrieves a value from a closed workbook
    Dim arg As String
'   Make sure the file exists
    If Right(path, 1) <> "\" Then path = path & "\"
    If Dir(path & file) = "" Then
        GetValue = "File Not Found"
        Exit Function
    End If
'   Create the argument
    arg = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!" & _
      Range(ref).Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1)
'   Execute an XLM macro
    GetValue = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
End Function
```

```
Sub TestGetValue()
    p = "c:\XLFiles\Budget"
    f = "Budget.xls"
    s = "Sheet1"
    a = "A1"
    MsgBox GetValue(p, f, s, a)
End Sub
```

Is there any way to get this to work with direct HTTP links to Excel workbooks instead of directories? Downloading them all into my computer isn't really an option, unless I could somehow change it to download each workbook automatically, get the value and then delete it, or something like that?